# Smooth scroll when scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have this JavaScript code ([PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ERWQR3u0), [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Tj5E5/)) which scrolls smoothly. It works just perfect but it needs one more thing:

```
var EPPZScrollTo =
{
    /**
     * Helpers.
     */
    documentVerticalScrollPosition: function()
    {
        if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset; // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) return document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6 (standards mode).
        if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8.
        return 0; // None of the above.
    },

    viewportHeight: function()
    { return (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat") ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight; },

    documentHeight: function()
    { return (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight; },

    documentMaximumScrollPosition: function()
    { return this.documentHeight() - this.viewportHeight(); },

    elementVerticalClientPositionById: function(id)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        var rectangle = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rectangle.top;
    },

    /**
     * Animation tick.
     */
    scrollVerticalTickToPosition: function(currentPosition, targetPosition)
    {
        var filter = 0.1;
        var fps = 60;
        var difference = parseFloat(targetPosition) - parseFloat(currentPosition);

        // Snap, then stop if arrived.
        var arrived = (Math.abs(difference) <= 0.5);
        if (arrived)
        {
            // Apply target.
            scrollTo(0.0, targetPosition);
            return;
        }

        // Filtered position.
        currentPosition = (parseFloat(currentPosition) * (1.0 - filter)) + (parseFloat(targetPosition) * filter);

        // Apply target.
        scrollTo(0.0, Math.round(currentPosition));

        // Schedule next tick.
        setTimeout("EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalTickToPosition("+currentPosition+", "+targetPosition+")", (2000 / fps));
    },

    /**
     * For public use.
     *
     * @param id The id of the element to scroll to.
     * @param padding Top padding to apply above element.
     */
    scrollVerticalToElementById: function(id, padding)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element == null)
        {
            console.warn('Cannot find element with id \''+id+'\'.');
            return;
        }

        var targetPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition() + this.elementVerticalClientPositionById(id) - padding;
        var currentPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition();

        // Clamp.
        var maximumScrollPosition = this.documentMaximumScrollPosition();
        if (targetPosition > maximumScrollPosition) targetPosition = maximumScrollPosition;

        // Start animation.
        this.scrollVerticalTickToPosition(currentPosition, targetPosition);
    }
};
```

I would like it to stop auto-scrolling upon scroll. As it is right now, it messes up when you scroll at the same time of it auto-scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional variable that you use to keep track of has user started scrolling.

```
var user_is_scrolling = false;
```

Then schedule the next scroll only if the user hasn't started scrolling:

```
if(!user_is_scrolling){
    setTimeout("EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalTickToPosition("+currentPosition+", "+targetPosition+")", (2000 / fps));
}
```

Then keep track of the window scroll events

```
var scroll_timeout;
window.onscroll = function(e) {

    //clear the timeout if it happens to exist
    clearTimeout(scroll_timeout);


    //set scrolling to true
    user_is_scrolling = true;

    //set timeout for setting user_is_scrolling to false 250ms after 
    //user has actually stopped scrolling
    scroll_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       user_is_scrolling = false;
    }, 250);    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UT8H6/4/